# javascript - call math.rand, then scale and convert to int, in a function argumnet

Tags: javascript, math

I need to perform the specified operations within the argumnts of a function. I saw this done once but I disremember the syntax.

Comment: Disremember - I love that word.

Comment: what do you mean by _scale_ it?

Comment: Well, functions and whatnot, but let me change the tag if I am wrong

Answer (score 3):

**Original answer** *see below for updated answer*

> ...to perform the specified operations within the argumnts of a function...

I have no idea what "within" might mean there. :-)

But perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
function foo(num) {
    return Math.round(Math.rand() * num);
}
```

More reading:

- MDN's pages on the [`Math` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

---

**Updated answer**

Re your comment below:

> I need the math to happen where it says "num" :).

You can't do that in JavaScript. When declaring a function, all you can put where I have `num` above is the names of formal arguments. You can't have expressions there.

You *can* do this, though:

```
function foo(num) {
    num = Math.round(Math.rand() * num);

    // ...and use `num`...
}
```

There's a very slight performance penalty for doing that rather than creating a new `var` within the function, e.g.:

```
function foo(n) {
    var num = Math.round(Math.rand() * n);

    // ...and use `num`...
}
```

...but it's *very* slight, likely to be washed out by whatever else you're doing.

Comment: I need the math to happen where it says "num" :). Sorry for the edit, a misclick.

Comment: @jamesson: You mean the `num` in `function foo(num)`? You can't do that. (See edit)

Comment: Sorry, reloaded too slow (must rduce caffeine intake =P.

Comment: you _could_ do that if `num` was an object. It doesn't work for non-objects

Comment: I love ppl who talk about performance, makes my tail all bushy =P. In all seriousness, I hope to deploy to as many platforms as possible so performance for me is a biggie.

Comment: what i mean is this: `function foo(o) { o.key = 'newValue'; } <br> var O = { key: 'val' }; foo(O);` will change the value of `O.key` to 'newValue'. This happens since objects are passed as reference, unlike other types

Comment: @ParthThakkar: I don't think affecting the value in the calling context is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: ok...so it seems like today i am not getting any of the questions being asked! Shoot!!! But anyways, I finally crossed a ton of reputation. :)